# I want the SingleChildScrollView to stay fixed

Tags: flutter, dart

I used `SingleChildScrollView` in the table I created friends. I want SingleChildScrollView to stay on the screen all the time, how can I do this (i.e. I don't want it to be shown only when I come with the mouse)

**my code**
[enter link description here](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/zNdQFQX8XF/)

**I want the scrollbar to stay fixed**
[image]

Comment: stay on the screen all the time? can you share some code?

Comment: I shared it bro, thank you

Comment: you scroll your view, this is a normal reaction of `SingleChildScrollView`, if you want to split the table and `SingleChildScrollView` you need to add an additional `SingleChildScrollView`, in this case you need to remove the scroll indicator from the second

Comment: I want the ico to be permanent.
I didn't quite understand what you were saying.

Comment: what do you mean by "stay on the screen all the time"? if you want permanent `SingleChildScrollView`, add parameter `physics: NeverScrollablePhysics()` to `SingleChildScrollView`

Comment: Sir, how can I give color to singlechildscrollview?

Answer (score 1):

wrap your List with ScrollBar.
set `isAlwaysShown = true`

```
Scrollbar(
    isAlwaysShown: true,
    child: GridView.builder(
      itemCount: 10,
      gridDelegate:
        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 3),
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return Center(
          child: Text('item $index'),
        );
      },
    ),
  );
```

Comment: thank you very much